# Faculty search decision timeline

Tags: job-search

I had a campus interview at the U.S. R1 University (Assistant Professor, Social Sciences) in the second half of November 2022. The interview went well, I was asked when I can start the job. I received responses from all SC members for my thank you note after the visit. References were called in mid-December. Right before Christmas break I received message from SC Chair saying that they finalized feedback for all candidates and submitted them to College Dean and Dept. Chair. He mentioned that I am still under consideration and I am a very good candidate but ultimate decision and offer to be made by Dean and she cannot share any other info at this point. It is almost two months since my interview, I have another campus interview coming and I guess my question would be - should I request update on my status and inform them about another campus interview or stay quiet?

Comment: *Usually* informing the potential employer that you may have other options as well raises your value in their eyes and makes them move a bit faster. *When exactly* to do it is another question. You might want to wait until the other interview actually takes place and you get at least some vague idea of what to expect there, but I'm not really sure here.

Comment: So what happened with the OP? @Farlas?

Comment: Still wondering what happened to the OP...

Answer (score 1):

It's still the holidays in the United States, so I imagine this might contribute to the slowness of a response. This does not seem out of the ordinary.